# Perfomance of local variables in loops

Tags: c, for-loop, stack

does gcc or clang optimize the following code without an additional local variable declaration

```
void loop (int* array) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
      printf ("%i", array[i])
   }
}
```

to be equally perfomant as this one, with an additional local variable inside a for loop on the stack?

```
void loop (int* array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
     int helper_variable = array [i];
     printf ("%i", helper_variable)
  }
}
```

Best wishes,
tt

Comment: Why do you think that the second is more optimal than the first? The compiler is likely to *remove* the unnecessary local variable.

Comment: See the generated assembly and compare the two. Do they compile down to the same code?

Comment: `array` in the second snippet is not a pointer to `int`, it's an `int`. You can't subscript it like an array.

Comment: *"to be equally perfomant as this one,"* ===> How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Compilers have been able to quite effortlessly optimize away temporary variables for several decades by now.

Comment: Equally perfomant would mean, same number of steps, which results in the stack operation for the local variable removed.

Comment: the generated assembler code is exactly the same with `-O1` so the programs are identical

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with at least `-O1`, gcc and clang do optimize them out. You can check these kind of questions on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/Pjvzzos55

Comment: That's a very cool site, thank you.